# Text overriding while concating text with array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

I am tring to concat three strings. first and last are hard-coded. Middle string is an element of array. While adding the last text is not appending at the end, but at the beginning of text. Also it is over riding the number of characters from the beginning. If I remove the array element and replace it with a hard-coded text then the code works fine.

```js
    var a="/q/scene";
    var b= list[0]; //where list[0] is "/canvas/myText"
    var c= ".write"
    console.Log(a+b+c);
```

Output: .writene/canvas/myText

On replacing var b with "asd"
output: /q/sceneasd.write

Comment: note sure how that would be possible. Can you make an example that actually shows the problem? I am guessing your code is actually not `a + b + c`

Comment: And someone made it runnable when list is not defined....

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ludovico um, it is not producing what OP says it is....

Comment: @ludovico It produces the correct result, not what the OP says.

Comment: The issue is something else, should be closed since details are not available to reproduce.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you correct the syntax error in `console.Log()` and that your array really does have what you say it does, the code executes as it should:

```js
var list = ["/canvas/myText"];

var a="/q/scene";
var b= list[0]; //where list[0] is "/canvas/myText"
var c= ".write"
console.log(a+b+c);
```

Comment: @ludovico I tested it in Chrome and it works as expected. Just as it works in the snippet. And, in your comment, you state that you get the expected result in both places, which is NOT what the OP says.

Answer (score -2):

Your code works fine.

```js
let list = [ '/canvas/myText', 'thing 2' ]
var a="/q/scene";
var b= list[0]; //where list[0] is "/canvas/myText"
var c= ".write"
console.log(a+b+c);
```